# UIPasteboard Cut Paste Select buttons not showing up as expected

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, uitextview

Experiencing the following behavior in all of our UITextViews.  Have not seen any posts on this issue to-date.

1. First entry into the Application works as expected (Can paste, select, cut or copy text).
2. After exiting application and reentry, standard UIPasteboard buttons do not show up.
3. This effects all UITextViews in the app.  There is no custom UIPasteboard code.

Spyglass and blue text selection handles will display without menus.  The symptoms appears as if `[UIMenuController setMenuVisible:NO]` has been called.  We have no code that does this.

We simply want Copy and Paste to work consistently for our UITextView's.

If we reboot the phone, or delete and rebuild the App, it works fine the first time executed, and then ends up in this state from the 2nd execution on.

What might we be doing that would be triggering this behavior?